# Moving parts right in two - dimensional matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I would like to get your help to understand and finish my program.

This is what I have to do:

> "You must exercise program that:
>   First. An absorbing two - dimensional integer arr [M] [N]. M - number of rows N - number of columns. (Matrix size was received from the user)
>   Two. The program uses auxiliary functions "shift" moves the values ​​of the matrix to the right one place, as shown in the picture (2 entered instead of 1, 3 instead of 2, 4 instead of 3, ... 20 instead of 19, first place 20).
>   Shift have to write a function and call her three times in the sample matrix loop .."

Example
[image]

My problems are:

1. I don't know how to do the matrix two - dimensional integer arrays that there size is entered by the user. I only know  by DEFINE SIZE of the row and the cols
2. My function isn't close to the real deal so I would like to get help finish my function.

My output:

[image: my execution]

My code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define M 4
#define N 5
void shift (int arr[M][N], int length); 

void main()
{
    int arr[M][N];
    int i,j,length;

    printf("Enter %d rows \n",M);
    for (i=0 ; i<M ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Enter %d numbers:\n",N);
        for(j=0 ; j<N ; j++ )
        { 
            scanf("%d" , &arr[i][j] );
        }
    length=N+M;
    }
    shift (arr,length);
    system("pause");
    return ;
}

void shift (int arr[M][N], int length) 
{    
    int i,j,temp;
    temp=arr[0][0];
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
             for(j=0; j<N-1 ; j++)
             {
                 printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);

             }
             arr[i][j]=temp;
             printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Edit: pictures resized

Comment: Those images contain way too much whitespace...

Answer (score 1):

```
Shifts all columns to the right. 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void shift_columns_right(int M[100][100], int rows, int cols) {

    int tmp_lastcol;
    int j, k;

    for (j = 0; j<rows; j++){
        tmp_lastcol = M[j][cols-1];
        for (k = cols-1;  k > 0; k-- ){
            M[j][k] = M[j][k-1];
        }
        M[j][0] = tmp_lastcol;
    }

}
int main(void){

    int B[100] [100] = { 
                   {1,2,3,4}, 
                   {5,6,7,8}, 
                   {9,10,11,12}, 
                   {13,14,15,16}, 
                   {17,18,19,20}, 
    };

    shift_columns_right(B,5,4);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will you give a hint as how to shift the elements. The logic is to swap the elements between the current and last element in the row as you iterate. I will show you a working example on 1D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

int main()
{
    int a[ARRAY_SIZE] = {11,22,33,44,55};
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[ARRAY_SIZE-1];
        a[ARRAY_SIZE-1] = temp;
    }

    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 55  11  22  33  44

To dynamically allocate the memory for array, use `malloc`. Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the hint.but my problam is how to set a 2d array.I would liek to get an article or something to understand this subject more

Comment: Just google how to dynamically allocate a 2D array and you will be flooded with results. And regarding, the swap on 2D array, all you have to do is to add another loop to iterate over other rows in my logic.

Comment: Hey Masesh! I got a problem i would like to get your help